# What is range of the in-built Bluetooth of the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I want to buy a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but I want to know what the range of the Bluetooth is.

It has in-built Bluetooth 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I use Raspberry Pi 3 to communicate with Arduino using HC-05 Bluetooth module on the Arduino side.

I try it on my home and it works only for about 5 meters only

Answer (score 0):

The range depends on various factors like

1. physical obstacles.
2. Receiver
3. Transmitter power etc.

You can have a good connectivity within a 60-70 mts range for Bluetooth 4.1. I have used at my home but at times it disconnects. I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 with a Bluetooth adapter connected to the AmazonBasics Bluetooth speakers.

check the Bluetooth documentation (bluez) for more details.

Comment: I think the OP might not be interested in the results you have with an external adapter.